# Prove that $\dim(U \cap W) = 2$ and $U + W = V.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Assume that $U$ and $W$ are distinct subspaces of a four-dimensional vector space $V$ and $\dim(U) = \dim(W) = 3.$ Prove that $\dim(U \cap W) = 2$ and $U + W = V.$

This is easy to prove with the fact that $\dim(U) + \dim(V) - \dim(U \cap V) = \dim(U + V).$ How could we prove this without?

Edit: Here's my proof after the given hints, I would like to know if it is correct! Thanks!

Take $x \in U \subset V$ such that $x \not\in W.$ As $W$ is a subspace, $0 \in W,$ and so $ x = x + 0 \in U + W.$ Hence $V \subset U+W.$ Now let $x \in U + W.$ Then $x = u + w$ for some $u \in U, w \in W.$ But since $U,W \subset V,$ the vectors $u$ and $w$ are also vectors in $v.$ Thus $x = u + w \in V$ and so $U + W \subset V.$ Combined with the fact that $V \subset U + W,$ one has $V = U + W.$ \ \vspace{1mm} Now let $\mathfrak{B}_1 = (v_1,\ldots,v_m)$ be a basis of $U \cap W$ so that $\dim(U \cap W) = m.$ Since $\mathfrak{B}_1$ is a basis for $U \cap W,$ it is linearly independent in $U$ and hence can be extended to a basis $\mathfrak{B}_1 \cup (u_1,\ldots,u_k) = \mathfrak{B}_2$ of $U.$ Similarly, $\mathfrak{B}_1$ can be extended to basis $\mathfrak{B}_1 \cup (w_1,\ldots,w_j) = \mathfrak{B}_3$ of $W.$ Note that $\dim U = m + k = 3$ and $\dim W = m + j = 3$ We now prove that $\mathfrak{C} = (v_1,\ldots,v_m,u_1,\ldots,u_k,w_1,\ldots,w_j)$ is a basis of $U + W.$ We know that $\operatorname{span}(\mathfrak{C})$ contains $U$ and $W$ and so $U + W \subset \operatorname{span}(\mathfrak{C}).$ Suppose that $$(\star) \hspace{1mm} a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_m v_m + b_1u_1 + \cdots + b_k u_k + c_1 w_1 + \cdots + c_j w_j = 0$$ where the $a$'s, $b$'s, and $c$'s are elements of a field $F.$ The preceding equality can be written $$c_1w_1 + \cdots + c_j w_j =  -b_1u_1 - \cdots - b_k u_k - a_1 v_1 - \cdots - a_m v_m,$$ \ demonstrating that $c_1w_1 + \cdots + c_j w_j \in U.$ All the $w$'s are in $W,$ so this implies $c_1w_1 + \cdots + c_j w_j \in U \cap W.$ Because $(v_1,\ldots,v_m)$ is a basis for $U \cap W,$ we can write $c_1w_1 + \cdots + c_j w_j = d_1 v_1 + \cdots + d_m v_m$ for some choice of scalars $d_1,\ldots,d_m.$ But $\mathfrak{B}_3$ is a basis and hence linearly independent, so the previous equation implies that all the $c$'s and $d$'s are equal to $0.$ Thus $(\star)$ becomes $a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_m v_m + b_1u_1 + \cdots + b_k u_k = 0.$ But $\mathfrak{B}_2$ is linearly independent also, so all the $a$'s and $b$'s are equal to $0$ as well. Hence $\mathfrak{C}$ is linearly independent and is a basis for $U + W$ with length $m + k + j.$ Using the fact that $V = U + W,$ we have $$4 = \dim(V) = \dim(U+W) = m + k + j = (m+k)+(m+j) - m = 3 + 3 - m.$$ Thus we have $4 = 6 - m.$ Solving for $m,$ we obtain $m=2,$ and thus $\dim(U \cap W) = m = 2.\Box$

Comment: I think that your proof is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

For $U+W=V$: take $x\in U$ s.t. $x\not\in W$. (Why this is possible?)

For $\dim(U\cap W) = 2$: take a basis of $U\cap W$.

Comment: @copper.hat, $U\subset V$ trivially because is a subspace.

Comment: @copper.hat, I've corrected the typo. Thanks.

Comment: Good hints, thank you

Comment: Do I need to prove $U+W = V$ first? That way I can use that $\dim(U+W) = 4.$ I can't seem to get anywhere assuming that $\beta = (v_1,\ldots,v_m)$ is basis of length $m$ and then trying to extend $\beta$ so that $\beta \cup (u_1,\ldots,u_k)$ is a basis of $U$ of length $m + k = 3$ and $\beta \cup (w_1,\ldots,w_j)$ is a basis of $W$ with length $3 = m + j$

Comment: Yes, I've edited the answer for changing the order of hints.

Comment: Thanks! How does the proof look?

Answer (score 1):

Since $W$ has codimension $1$ in $V$, $W\cap U$ has codimension $\le 1$ in $U$. If the codimension were $0$, we'd have $W\cap U=U$, $U\supseteq W$, $U=W$.